# Jquery toggle or add and remove two different classes with drop slide menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Having a bit of difficulty trying to add and remove a class with toggle. What I’m trying to accomplish is,
When the user clicks on the “search magnify glass” button image/icon, a dropdown menu slides down from the top and the clicked “search magnify glass” button image/icon,  turns into “closed”(x) button image/icon,. 
Then when the user clicks on the “closed”(x) button image/icon,, the drop menu slides back up and the “closed” button/icon turns back into  a “search” button/icon again.
code, posted  on jfiddle:

```
<div>  
    </div>
```

Here is my jfiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/nicban/wLwxaw3a/24/

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I needed the search button image to change to a close button image when the top menu opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to toggle the button.
I got something working by adding `$('#searchdropdown').toggleClass('close-button');` to your JS in the click function. But you will probably want to clean it up.

Comment: Thank you that was it!! I updated my jfiddle code and it solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help!